# Removing the numbers that appears at the end of text under a columns of data frames

Tags: python, regex, dataframe

I want to do a bit cleaning and removing the numbers that appears at the end of text but depending on its ids the cleaning is different, I know how to do it when it is a dictionary and I developed the code as follows but what if I have a data frame ? with id as one column and another column named text that has to be cleaned. how do I change this code?

```
def remove(dic):
    suffix_map = {
        "id1": r'(?:0)$',
        "id2": r'(?:1)$',
        "id3": r'(?:2)$',
        "id4": r'(?:3)$',
    }

    for key, val in dic.items():
        suffix_pattern = suffix_map.get(key)
        if suffix_pattern:
            val.columns = val.columns.str.replace(suffix_pattern, '', regex=True)
            val.columns = val.columns.str.replace(r'_$', '', regex=True)

    return dic

the initioal dataframe:

df1 = pd.DataFrame([{'id': "id1", 'text': 'x11'}, {'id': "id2", 'text': 'x342'}, {'id': "id2",'text': 'b34'}])

the final output: 

out = pd.DataFrame([{'id': "id1", 'text': 'x1'}, {'id': "id2", 'text': 'x34'}, {'id': "id2",'text': 'b34'}])
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of `dic` and the matching expected output. is `dic` a `DataFrame`?

Comment: I already have the result for a given dictionary I want to perform it on data frame

Comment: I added the sample of initial data frame and the out put

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html#flexible-apply):

```
suffix_map = {
        "id1": r'(?:1)$',
        "id2": r'(?:2)$',
        "id3": r'(?:3)$',
        "id4": r'(?:4)$',
    }

df1['text'] = (df1.groupby('id', group_keys=False)['text']
                  .apply(lambda s: s.str.replace(suffix_map[s.name], '', regex=True))
              )

print(df1)
```

Or, with an explicit `for` loop:

```
for k, g in df1.groupby('id'):
    df1.loc[g.index, 'text'] = (df1.loc[g.index, 'text']
                                   .str.replace(suffix_map[k], '', regex=True)
                               )
print(df1)
```

Output:

```
    id text
0  id1   x1
1  id2  x34
2  id2  b34
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `df` like `df = pd.DataFrame([{'id': 1, 'text': 'foo'}, {'id': 2, 'text': 'bar'}])`, then you can apply a function to each cell in a column via

```
df["text"] = df.text.apply(lambda x: my_func(x))
```

Comment: but this functions that I wrote takes a dictionary how can I apply it to a data frame !